# how to style the result a php value that is been echo in an javascript onclick button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day guys, i am having an issue with this line of code, i echo a php echo value in a javascript submit function, which worked very perfect

[image]

using this button code

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="onclickbutton(<?php echo ($level->getAmount()); ?><?php echo($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?> )">
    Recycle
</button>
```

but the only issue am having is that i want to separate each value to look like this exactly.

Comment: Use comma `,` to separate parameters  i.e. `<?php echo ($level->getAmount()); ?>,<?php echo($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?>`

Comment: this is how i want it to look like<div class="modal-body">
       Amount: 5000<br/>
       Potential Earning: 10000
     </p>
      </div>